# Generics and Class, deciding subclass in constructor

Tags: java, generics

I want to be able to have (one of) my constructor decide what implementation of list it wants to use. The code I came up with compiles just fine without warnings but the IDE (eclipse) complains on the commented line, why and how do you infer the type?

```
public class GenericClassTest<T> {

private List<T> list;

//stuff...

public GenericClassTest(Class<? extends List> listCreator)
        throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
    this.list = listCreator.newInstance(); // how to infer type T? where
                                            // does diamondoperator go?
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws InstantiationException,
        IllegalAccessException {
    GenericClassTest<Integer> one = new GenericClassTest<>(ArrayList.class);
    GenericClassTest<String> two = new GenericClassTest<>(LinkedList.class);
    one.list.add(13);
    two.list.add("Hello");
    System.out.println(one.list);
    System.out.println(two.list);
}


}
```

Comment: What happens if you do `Class<? extends List<T>> listCreator`?

Comment: @BuhakeSindi Compile Error

Comment: The warning disappears but how do you infer the type in the parameter ArrayList.class then?

Comment: I will add `@SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })` before the constructor to make Eclipse silent.

Comment: Best way to make eclipse silent is to use intellij...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't really need to. Remember that `type-erasure` is going to replace the `T` with `Object` at runtime anyway. So at runtime you will always have a `List<Object>`. Therefore, it doesn't really matter if `T` is part of the construction call since it is ignored anyway. Generics are a compile-time convenience, they do not do a lot at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to have the generics in your code, then try this:

```
class Sample {
    static <T,L extends List<T>> L newList(Class<L> clazz) 
        throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
        return clazz.newInstance();
    }

    static <T> void mainCode() throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
        List<T> list;
        list = Sample.<String, ArrayList<String>>newList(ArrayList.class);      
    }
```